# Function arguments in algorithmicx

Tags: algorithmicx

I have a question about function arguments in the *algorithmicx* package. The following code works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[5]
  \Function{f}{$\tau$ , $\delta$}
  %\Function{f}{$\overrightarrow{\tau}$, $\overrightarrow{\delta}$}
  \State etc
  \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

But if I change the arguments to:

```
   \Function{f}{$\overrightarrow{\tau}$ , $\overrightarrow{\delta}$}
```

I get an apparently unrelated error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@gtempa.
```

Do you know any solutions or workarounds for this situation?

Comment: Please edit your question so the code is a full document using any packages. I tried `\usepackage{algorithmicx}` but got `! Undefined control sequence.
l.11    \Function`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edited the question with a complete example code; I hope that's OK.

Comment: I'm sorry for the incomplete example, and thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 9):

If in doubt, try `\protect`...

```
  \Function{f}{$\protect\overrightarrow{\tau}$, $\protect\overrightarrow{\delta}$}
```

[image]

Comment: "If in doubt, try `\protect...`".  I will add this to my list of memorable quotes.